# Issue in .CSHTML pages while loading the blog as virtual directory in iis6

Tags: razor, iis-6, virtual-directory

Anyone Please Help,

I believe this doubt is pretty out dated, but if any expert could nail it easily for me.

We have created an application using umbraco CMS and created a blog using BlogEngine 2.8 in Web Matrix, everything works awesomely fine in localhost.

When i moved complete website and blog to the staging server in iis6 am facing issues while i run my blog it loads fine, but while i click on Dashboard it throws me the below error.

Exception type: InvalidOperationException 
    Exception message: Could not locate Razor Host Factory type: umbraco.MacroEngines.RazorUmbracoFactory, umbraco.MacroEngines

I have already done the below:

Since i setup the blog in virtual directory, i commented out the inherited child application's handlers.

Am using the same application pool for both application and virtual directory.

Also, I added and removed the below in between        in Blog web.config

```
<security>
<requestFiltering>
    <fileExtensions>
        <remove fileExtension=".cshtml" />
        <add fileExtension=".cshtml" allowed="true" />
    </fileExtensions>
  </requestFiltering>
```

Added and removed the below key in app settings in Blog web.config

uncommented the below from blog web.config

```
<!-- you may need it if you have issuew with razor/ajax in admin cshtml pages -->
<buildProviders>
    <add extension=".cshtml" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider, System.Web.WebPages.Razor"/>
</buildProviders>
```

Please anyone of you guys let me know how to fix this.

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: Yes i resolved the above issue, follow the above error.